# E2E - How to test login with fake data - username and password?

Tags: automated-testing, protractor, integration-testing

I do have an angular login page build as a SPA: **`http://localhost:port/login`** which works fine. And I wrote an E2E integration test for that. It runs fine regarding checking the input-text for **`username`** and **`password`** and also the submit-button enabled/disabled based on if the input fields are empty or not.

Now I'am at the stage where I want to test a failed login process when the credentials (**`username`** and **`password`**) are not correct. But the test failed and I keep getting the following error:

**`1) user-app App should not login with wrong username and wrong password
  - Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: true`**.

Here is the code for this specific login case:

```
it("should not login with wrong username and wrong password", () => {

     const userNameInput = element(by.name('username'));
     const userPassInput = element(by.name('password'));
     const submitButton = element( by.css(".login-btn") );

     userNameInput.sendKeys('johnfoo');
     userPassInput.sendKeys('3edF!4rfv');

     expect(submitButton.isEnabled()).toBe(true);

     submitButton
         .click()
         .then(() => {
             browser.waitForAngular();
             browser.sleep(1000);
             expect(page.validationMessage().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
             expect(page.validationMessage().isDisplayed())
                                            .toMatch('Please check your username and/or password and try again!');
         });
});
```

Any idea or hint how to fix this? Habe been searching and found some old postings also in Stack Overflow, but they seem to be in a way different than the one I'am facing.

Comment: Fix what? Invalid login is rejected, which is correct response.

Comment: I'am trying to check if the error message is being displayed in this case. Thus, the expected behavior should be to display the error message in the UI - which is in this case: `Please check your username and/or password and try again!`.

Comment: Where is validationMessage() defined? And why it is a function instead of being an object?

Comment: Where is the ng-app directive defined in the HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

Protractor waits for the [Angular zone](https://medium.com/@MertzAlertz/what-the-hell-is-zone-js-and-why-is-it-in-my-angular-2-6ff28bcf943e) to stabilise in case of Angular apps. If the stabilisation is taking long time, then your tests will timeout since the async operations around Angular's `zone.js` are probably taking more time to complete and would block your tests from continuing.

The best workaround is to have your tests not wait for this synchronisation to complete.

So you can set `browser.ignoreSynchronisation = true` or `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false` [I prefer the earlier one].

Edit : You can also try using `useAllAngular2AppRoots: true` in your `config.js` file , and see it that resolves the error.

Comment: unfortunately the hint didn't help. Keep throwing same message: `✗ should not login with wrong username and wrong password
      - Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: true at runWaitForAngularScript.then(/Users/myUserName/projects/UserApp/19_12-t-04_16/user-app/node_modules/protractor/lib/browser.ts:653:19 ...`

Comment: @k.vincent see the Edit in my answer.

Comment: Nope, keeps the same.

Comment: Are you using `$timeout` anywhere in your Angular app code?

Comment: No, I'am not using it. Actually that the test failed is i a way correct is correct, but the issue is how to get rid of the error-message: `- Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: true`, or to prevent print in it out in the terminal.

Comment: `$timeout` would have used by your devs, not you. Please check it.

Comment: Please check this issue - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4336

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70889/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-demouser123).